How to execute a long running process in the background without it blocking the rest of the React app?
I have a React app that must execute a long running process when a certain page is loaded. This process is currently blocking the page from being rendered while it is running.
What I have tried:
  useEffect(() => {
    async function async_wrapper() {

        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          execut_long_running_process();
        });

    }

    async_wrapper();

  }, []);

This also does not work:
  useEffect(() => {
    async function async_wrapper() {

        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          execut_long_running_process();
        });

    }

    async_wrapper();

  }, []);

Inside execut_long_running_process, an AJV object compiles a validator function for some given schema. I cannot control how the ajv.compile method works.

Both snippets lead to a synchronous exeuction of execut_long_running_process. The long-running process itself, that is, the contents of execut_long_running_process must use asynchronous techniques, and you have not shown us that part of the code.

@HeikoTheißen Inside the execut_long_running_process, an AJV object compiles a validator function for some given schema. I cannot control how the ajv.compile method works?

You should probably consider using the Web Workers API to perform a long running task in the background off the main JS thread. You may want to checkout this article - https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/10/tasks-react-app-web-workers/
